# Multidimensional array is overwriting instead of appending

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have a Wordpress site with Woocommerce Subscriptions. I want to list all products and within each product I want to list each subscription (if any) and the subscription status (active, cancelled, on-hold etc). I have managed to list all products in an array, but I have trouble organizing it. Here is an example snippet:

```
[
    {
        "bod_id": "3557",
        "bod_navn": "CS 01",
        "order_id": "4153",
        "sub_id": "4154",
        "sub_status": "wc-active"
    },
    {
        "bod_id": "3557",
        "bod_navn": "CS 01",
        "order_id": "4570",
        "sub_id": null,
        "sub_status": null
    },
    {
        "bod_id": "3557",
        "bod_navn": "CS 01",
        "order_id": "4631",
        "sub_id": null,
        "sub_status": null
    }
]
```

Full result page can be found here: https://inboxlager.no/bodoversikt/index4.php

"bod_id" is the product ID and I want to have 1 product per array item. After that comes "bod_navn" which is the name of the product. In the example "order_id" is listed, but it's not needed for anything other than a link between the product and each subscription within the product.

**Using the above example I want the result to be more or less like this (subs appended):**
(The results with null is not really wanted also, I just added them to show appending and to use same example as before)

```
[
    {
        "bod_id": "3557",
        "bod_navn": "CS 01",
        "subs": {
            "sub_id": "4154" {
                "sub_status": "wc-active"
            },
            "sub_id": "null" {
                sub_status": "null"
            },
            "sub_id": "null" {
                sub_status": "null"
            }
    }
]
```

After trying a bit to solve this I got a little closer, but still not good enough. A snippet of the result:

```
{
    "3557": {
        "bod_id": "3557",
        "bod_navn": "CS 01",
        "subs": {
            "sub_id": {
                "sub_status": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full result page can be found here: https://inboxlager.no/bodoversikt/index5.php

As you see, the [] are gone. But more importantly; the sub_id keeps getting overwritten and only the last row is presented. I have 2 theories how to solve this, but I don't know how to execute them properly.

1. Run a separate array with subs and then somehow merge after.
2. Run an SQL query specific for subs connected to the product ID within the while loop.

Or maybe there is a better way to fix this?

These are the database tables that I can use:

```
wp_2_posts

ID      post_title      post_status     post_type           post_parent
3557    CS 01           (not used)      product             (not used)
4154    (not used)      wc-active       shop_subscription   4153
4153    (not used)      (not used)      shop_order          (not used)
```

```
wp_2_wc_order_product_lookup

order_id    product_id
4153        3557
```

Here is the PHP file for the first example (this is not organized into per product, but resulting in every combination possible from query):

```
$boder = array();
$bod_sql = "
SELECT
    A.ID AS bod_id, A.post_title AS bod_navn, B.order_id,
    C.ID AS sub_id, C.post_status AS sub_status
FROM wp_2_posts A
    LEFT JOIN wp_2_wc_order_product_lookup B ON A.ID = B.product_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_2_posts C ON C.post_parent = B.order_id
WHERE A.post_type = 'product'
ORDER BY A.ID";
$bod_res = mysqli_query($conn,$bod_sql) or die("Last error: {$conn->error}\n");

while($bod_row = $bod_res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $boder[] = $bod_row;
}

$json = json_encode($boder, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

Here is the PHP file for my attempt (this is where it overwrites subs):

```
$boder = array();
$bod_sql = "
SELECT
    A.ID AS bod_id, A.post_title AS bod_navn, B.order_id,
    C.ID AS sub_id, C.post_status AS sub_status
FROM wp_2_posts A
    LEFT JOIN wp_2_wc_order_product_lookup B ON A.ID = B.product_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_2_posts C ON C.post_parent = B.order_id
WHERE A.post_type = 'product'
ORDER BY A.ID";
$bod_res = mysqli_query($conn,$bod_sql) or die("Last error: {$conn->error}\n");

while($bod_row = $bod_res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $boder[$bod_row['bod_id']] ['bod_id'] = $bod_row['bod_id'];
    $boder[$bod_row['bod_id']] ['bod_navn'] = $bod_row['bod_navn'];
    $boder[$bod_row['bod_id']] ['subs'] ['sub_id'] = $bod_row['sub_id'];
    $boder[$bod_row['bod_id']] ['subs'] ['sub_id'] ['sub_status'] = $bod_row['sub_status'];
}

$json = json_encode($boder, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

Comment: The reason you get one sub_id is because subs has one key sub_id with one value. A key in an associative array is unique in PHP. The result you posted is not directly possible, only something close if you create an array for subs and an array for each of those sub_ids.

Comment: Thank you @Remy! I think your point is close to my theory number 1. However, I don't know how to do that exactly. If you check the first full result page (https://inboxlager.no/bodoversikt/index4.php) and go to "bod_id: 3571" you can see that it has/had 2 subscriptions. One is cancelled and one is active.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, the reason that only one sub_id is displayed on the json object is that the associative array keys are unique in PHP. (on a side note the JSON syntax seems slightly incorrect as well).

To achieve something similar to the result you provided, you could go with the following:

```
while($bod_row = $bod_res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $boder[$bod_row['bod_id']] ['bod_id'] = $bod_row['bod_id'];
    $boder[$bod_row['bod_id']] ['bod_navn'] = $bod_row['bod_navn'];
    
    // Here we create an empty array for subs if that is not yet done.
    if (!isset($boder[$bod_row['bod_id']]['subs'])) {
        $boder[$bod_row['bod_id']]['subs'] = [];
    }

    // Then we push associative arrays of key value pairs
    // for each of the id and status pairs.
    $boder[$bod_row['bod_id']]['subs'][] = [
        'sub_id' => $bod_row['sub_id'],
        'sub_status' => $bod_row['sub_status']
    ];
}
```

This would result in the following JSON output:

```
{
    "3557":{
        "bod_id":"3557",
        "bod_navn":"CS 01",
        "subs":[
            {
                "sub_id":"4145",
                "sub_status":"wc-active"
            },
            {
                "sub_id":null,
                "sub_status":null
            },
            {
                "sub_id":null,
                "sub_status":null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To elaborate a little bit more, PHP converts the associative arrays to primitive json objects. And to hold multiple objects you really need an array that can store a collection of them, else it will override/re-assign a value to a property.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a go as soon as I'm back at the office tomorrow. I'll mark as answer asap if it works for me. I'm guessing it will. :)

Comment: Excellent! This is perfect! I need to learn more about arrays, json and advanced sql queries...